# Border in TableView Header change Colour in Dark Mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having a problem where I have a border on my header view that's not changing colour in dark mode. I understand this is because I am using CGColour but I am unsure how to fix this issue as I am creating the layer inside the function. It seems like it's cumbersome to create a whole new file to hold a border view to implement `traitCollectionDidChange()`. How can I fix this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.borderColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryColour")?.cgColor
    border.borderWidth = (1.0)
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 28, y: 33 - 1.0, width: folderTableView.frame.width-54, height: 1.0)

    view.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/?time=1426

Comment: The problem in your code is that you have set the color in `willDisplayHeaderView`. It isn’t going to change all by itself because it is not a UIColor, and `willDisplayHeaderView` is not magically going to be called again just because the user changed to dark mode.

Comment: @matt Please read my question, I understand why it's happening. I am asking for what the right way to go about the problem is.

Comment: Also what are you doing about the fact that header views are reusable? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make *some* arrangement to be notified when the trait collection is changed, so that you can have the layer redraw its border color. It isn't going to happen by itself, and `willDisplayHeaderView` is not going to be magically called again just because the mode changed.

Here is a simple iOS project demonstrating a CALayer that hears when the trait collection has changed and adjusts its own border color accordingly:

```
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer:layer)
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.borderColor = UIColor(named: "MyCoolColor")!.cgColor
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changed), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "traitCollectionDidChange"), object: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    @objc func changed(_:Notification) {
        self.borderColor = UIColor(named: "MyCoolColor")!.cgColor
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layer = MyLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        if self.traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "traitCollectionDidChange"), object: self)
        }
    }
}
```